# How can I covert AJAX to dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, pandas

I Have the following AJAX  submission data entry and I want to organize it in report format so I have to covert it to table format 
The table should include the field_name as header and the field_value as rows 
Can anyone help me?

```
[{"field_name":"patientno","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"patient_unhcr_id","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"jps_file","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"patient_individual_id","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"name","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"name_in_arabic","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"age","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"age_category","field_value":"U5"},
{"field_name":"gender","field_value":"F"},
{"field_name":"coo","field_value":"Syria"},
{"field_name":"phone_number","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"governorate","field_value":"Mafraq"},
{"field_name":"bank_branch","field_value":"\u0641\u0631\u0639 \u0636\u0627\u062d\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0646"},
{"field_name":"treatment_site","field_value":"Ramtha Governmental Hospital"},
{"field_name":"case_category","field_value":"CS"},
{"field_name":"description","field_value":"a"},
{"field_name":"eligibilities_","field_value":"Eligible Level 2"},{"field_name":"approved_amount_before_rounding","field_value":"21.5"},
{"field_name":"approved_amount","field_value":"20"},
{"field_name":"radio_buttons","field_value":"Yes"},
{"field_name":"recipient_name","field_value":"a"},
{"field_name":"recipient__dob","field_value":"02\/24\/2020"},
{"field_name":"gender_of_recpient_","field_value":"F"},
{"field_name":"recipient_unhcr_id_number","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"recipient_individual_id","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"relationship_to_patient","field_value":"Daughter-in-law"},
{"field_name":"recepient_phone_no","field_value":"1"},
{"field_name":"date_request_send_to_unhcr","field_value":"02\/17\/2020"},
{"field_name":"approval_date","field_value":"02\/24\/2020"},
{"field_name":"closure_date","field_value":"02\/11\/2020"},
{"field_name":"comment","field_value":"a"},
{"field_name":"attatchment","field_value":"http:\/\/192.168.1.52:9999\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/02\/IC-Weekly-Task-List-Template-8624.xlsx"}]
```

Comment: Checkout the `json` module - and specifically the `json.loads` method https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json

Answer (score 0):

Here is my crude approach, hope it helps

```
import pandas as pd

ajax = [{"field_name":"patientno","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"patient_unhcr_id","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"jps_file","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"patient_individual_id","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"name","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"name_in_arabic","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"age","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"age_category","field_value":"U5"},{"field_name":"gender","field_value":"F"},{"field_name":"coo","field_value":"Syria"},{"field_name":"phone_number","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"governorate","field_value":"Mafraq"},{"field_name":"bank_branch","field_value":"\u0641\u0631\u0639 \u0636\u0627\u062d\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u064a\u0627\u0633\u0645\u064a\u0646"},{"field_name":"treatment_site","field_value":"Ramtha Governmental Hospital"},{"field_name":"case_category","field_value":"CS"},{"field_name":"description","field_value":"a"},{"field_name":"eligibilities_","field_value":"Eligible Level 2"},{"field_name":"approved_amount_before_rounding","field_value":"21.5"},{"field_name":"approved_amount","field_value":"20"},{"field_name":"radio_buttons","field_value":"Yes"},{"field_name":"recipient_name","field_value":"a"},{"field_name":"recipient__dob","field_value":"02/24/2020"},{"field_name":"gender_of_recpient_","field_value":"F"},{"field_name":"recipient_unhcr_id_number","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"recipient_individual_id","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"relationship_to_patient","field_value":"Daughter-in-law"},{"field_name":"recepient_phone_no","field_value":"1"},{"field_name":"date_request_send_to_unhcr","field_value":"02/17/2020"},{"field_name":"approval_date","field_value":"02/24/2020"},{"field_name":"closure_date","field_value":"02/11/2020"},{"field_name":"comment","field_value":"a"},{"field_name":"attatchment","field_value":"http://192.168.1.52:9999/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/IC-Weekly-Task-List-Template-8624.xlsx"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ajax).T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
```

Basically you use ajax list as data to create a dataframe, transpose it, set the first row as headers and drop that row afterwards.